# Est-ce correct de dire « qu’as-tu fait de ta journée »?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

J’entends souvent cette tournure à l’oral, et elle heurte la sensibilité de mon oreille. À mon sens il serait préférable de dire « pendant la journée » ou « en journée » pour rester dans les limites du bon français.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C'est au contraire du "très bon français", du français littéraire.

> *Une voix sera là pour crier à toute heure :
>
> **Qu'as-tu fait de ta vie et de ta liberté ?**
>
> Crois-tu donc qu'on oublie autant qu'on le souhaite ?
>
> Crois-tu qu'en te cherchant tu te retrouveras ?
>
> De ton coeur ou de toi lequel est le poète ?*

Alfred de Musset, *La nuit d'août*, 1836